# In NestJS Mongoose, how to filter year field (string type) with a certain range of number?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

As I mentioned in the title, I want to query a string type field value by filtering it to a specific range of numbers.

For example, in a test table, I have row values ​​with random year values ​​between 2020 and 2040.
This value is of string type.

And, I'd like to search a list of between 2020 ~ 2025 year.

In this situation, what is the proper way to implement that query??

The table's and service's code is like below.

```js
// table entity
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Test {
  @Prop({ required: false, nullable: true, type: String })
  standard_year?: string;

  @Prop({ required: false, type: Boolean, default: false })
  is_deleted: boolean;

  // --- Meta fields ---
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId;

  // --- Meta fields ---
  createdAt: Date;

  // --- Meta fields ---
  updatedAt: Date;
}

const TestSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Test);

TestSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: function (doc, ret) {
    ret.id = ret._id;
    delete ret._id;
    delete ret.__v;
  },
});

TestSchema.virtual('id').get(function () {
  return this._id;
});

export { TestSchema };
```

```js
// service.ts
import { BadRequestException, forwardRef, Inject, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Test } from '../entities/test.entity';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
  private logger = new Logger(TestService.name);

  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Test.name)
    private readonly testModel: Model<Test>,
  ) {}

  /**
   * @summary search test data with year filter
   * @param standard_year
   */
  async getTestListWithYearFilter(
    standard_year: number,
  ): Promise<Test[]> {
    return await this.testModel
      .find({
        standard_year: // TODO ,
        is_deleted: false,
      })
      .exec()
      .then((testList) => {
        /**
         * @description
         */
        return testList;
      });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work to query a date between two

```
this.yourModel.find({
 date_field_you_want_to_search: {
    $gte: new Date(2012, 7, 14), // Greater or equal to this date
    $lt: new Date(2012, 7, 15) // Lower than this date
 }
})
```